# There is no currently active test exception in XUnit C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

When I start all tests, response was  ***There is no currently active test***. The problem took place when *ITestOutputHelper* write log to output window.

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(GetLogLevelString(logLevel))
              .Append(" [").Append(_categoryName).Append("] ")
              .Append(formatter(state, exception));

            if (exception != null)
            {
                sb.Append('\n').Append(exception);
            }

            _scopeProvider.ForEachScope((scope, state) =>
            {
                state.Append("\n => ");
                state.Append(scope);
            }, sb);

           
            **_testOutputHelper.WriteLine(sb.ToString());**
        }
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only can guess why it is so, maybe you use instance `_testOutputHelper` from test not related to current test. So this instance was injected for another test which was already completed.

The reason can be different, for example:

- you can forget to pass correct instance to use for logging
- some code can still call callbacks referencing old instance, maybe some static code or similar

**The common symptom will be that running single test is successful but running all tests or group of tests is failed.**

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. I built a proxy around ITestOutputHelper and implement following exception handling.
(seems like there is some "asynchronous" WriteLine-Call after Test is finished - i don't really know)

```
        public void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                _output.WriteLine(message);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }
```